# how to draw curve line in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am try to get a curve line just like the in Facebook comment session.
This line.

[image: the line]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this [code](https://github.com/dangngocduc/comment_tree/blob/edefe3f717247b46929d425109101f9602cdb4d7/lib/widgets/comment_child_widget.dart#L75):

```
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(avatarRoot!.width / 2, 0);
    path.cubicTo(
        avatarRoot!.width / 2,
        0,
        avatarRoot!.width / 2,
        padding!.top + avatarChild!.height / 2,
        avatarRoot!.width,
        padding!.top + avatarChild!.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, _paint!);
```

You will need learn to use `cubicTo` function